# activerecord :include count makes another query?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a `Show` that `has_many` `Artists`. When I query for a show, I `:include` `:artists` in it. However, 
when I do `shows.first.artists.count`, this results in a new query - which isn't very efficient.

My question is

a) Why is it query again which I :include artists in the query?

b) What can I do to stop this and avoid query every-time I call count

c) shows.first.artists.class is an array - is ActiveRecord overriding this method on array?

**Update**
Here's the code and query:

```
shows = Show.all :include => [:artists, :users], :limit => 12, :offset => 0
D, [2013-01-09T13:32:21.453346 #4659] DEBUG -- :   Show Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `shows`.* FROM `shows` WHERE `shows`.`deleted` = 0 LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
D, [2013-01-09T13:32:21.497766 #4659] DEBUG -- :   Artist Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `artists`.* FROM `artists` WHERE `artists`.`id` IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
D, [2013-01-09T13:32:21.513886 #4659] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`show_id` IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

And then I interate through artsits for count and it generates this query for artist :

```
  (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `artists` WHERE `artists`.`show_id` = 2
```

Comment: What's the SQL for the second query?

Comment: @Tyson I will update my question, one sec.

Answer (score 2):

While associations and arrays often behave the same there are some differences.

On an array `length`, `count`, `size` are all aliases for the same method.

On an association:

- `count` always does a `select count(*) from ...` query
- `length` always loads the entire association and then returns the length of the loaded array
- `size` will call `length` if the association is already loaded and `count` if not

Comment: Could you provide a reference to that, please?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L213

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shows.first.artists.size` instead to avoid the extra query.